# MySQL GROUP unless value equals 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like a query that groups the results together unless the value of job_num = 0 but I have been unable to work out how to do it.

This is my query as it stands (and doesn't work, I get a SQL error)...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM calls 
WHERE parent_id = '$term' GROUP BY IF (job_num != 0)
ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page
```

I have tried replacing `job_num != 0` with `job_num IS NOT NULL` and get the same result.

The rest of the query works fine until I tried to exclude the `job_num != 0`

This a simplified version of the table

```
id | call_ref | job_num
_______________________

1  | 123445   | 2389
_______________________

2  | 342537   | 0
_______________________

3  | 876483   | 2389
_______________________

4  | 644686   | 5643
_______________________

5  | 654532   | 0
```

I would like to group the rows where the job_num != 0 but I still want to display the rows where job_num = 0 just not grouped together.  The call_ref is not unique and there are a further 31 columns in the table I need the values of.

Using the above example rows with ids 1 and 3 would be grouped and 2,4 and 5 would still return results but not grouped.

The results I would like...

1 and 3 grouped (because the job_nums are the same but != 0)
2, 4, 5 not grouped

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  It is simply non-sensical to use `select *` with `group by`.

Comment: why don't put job_num != 0 in where clause ?

Comment: @mcNets because ideally I'd like to display the results with job_num != 0, I just don't want the results with that value grouped together

Comment: @GordonLinoff the table has 34 columns so may take me a while...

Comment: @tatty27 . . . All unaggregated columns in the `select` should be in the `group by`.  Your question is quite unclear.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @tatty27 I'm not familiar with GROUP BY IF, does it means: group all records less records that match the expression? Records that match 'job_id = 0' will be retrieved too?

Comment: @mcNets I tried the GROUP BY IF after searching stackoverflow before asking this question, indeed one of the answers to this question uses it (although it didn't work)

Comment: @tatty27 Maybe it is not the smartest solution, but you can get it with UNION

Comment: @mcNets could you show me an example please and if it works I can accept your answer?

Comment: @tatty27 ok, I post an answer but I'm not good with mysql

Comment: @tatty27 . . . What do you mean by "grouped"?  What are the results you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it with UNION?

```
(SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM calls 
WHERE parent_id = '$term' where job_num != 0 GROUP BY (job_num)
ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page)
UNION
(SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM calls 
WHERE parent_id = '$term' where job_num = 0
ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page);
```

Comment: Thanks but it comes up with a syntax error after the UNION.  Thanks for trying to help though :)  I will look at the UNION option more and see where the error is.

Comment: @tatty27 I've modified it according to mysql documentation

Comment: I don't downvote answers.  But this one deserves to be because it is using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There isn't column's name in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this request in PHP code Try

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM calls 
WHERE parent_id = \'$term\' GROUP BY IF job_num <> 0
ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page;
```

Comment: Thanks but gets a syntax error near 'job_num != 0 ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> @mcNets because ideally I'd like to display the results with job_num
>   != 0, I just don't want the results with that value grouped together

You do not want `group by` (although I don't understand what "that value" refers to).  I do note this is in direct contradiction of the first sentence of the question.

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS c.*
FROM calls c
WHERE c.parent_id = '$term' AND job_num <> 0
ORDER BY date_start DESC
LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page;
```

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you might just want rows with the value of 0 to appear together and the rest to appear together.  If that is the case, put the condition in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS c.*
FROM calls c
WHERE c.parent_id = '$term' 
ORDER BY (job_num = 0), date_start DESC
LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page;
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't display the rows where job_num != 0. I need the result to group the results by job_num where the job_num != 0 but I still need it to display the job_num = 0 rows too.  I will try and explain more in my question.

Comment: @tatty27 . . . This clearly displays the rows where `job_num` is not 0.  That is in the `where` clause.

Comment: yes, it does, but I want to see the rows where job_num is 0, just not grouped together.  I would like the rows with matching job_num values to be grouped except rows where job_num = 0 which are not grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
     FROM calls
     WHERE parent_id = '$term'
         AND job_num != 0
     GROUP BY job_num
     UNION SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
     FROM calls
     WHERE parent_id = '$term'
         AND job_num = 0) AS T
ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT $page_position,
                               $item_per_page
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table for the main query, then `LEFT JOIN` it on to the table that you want to display multiple rows for. For example:

```
SELECT      *
FROM (  
    SELECT      a.account_id 'CRM ID', a.lead_status 'Status', a.account_name 'Client Name', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL a.date_of_birth SECOND), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'DOB', a.postcode 'Postcode',
                a.phone 'Phone #.', a.email 'Email', IFNULL(i.invoice_date, 'Never') AS 'Last Invoice'
    FROM        mydb.invoices i
    RIGHT JOIN  mydb.members m      ON      i.member_id = m.member_id
    RIGHT JOIN  mydb.accounts a     ON      m.crm_id = a.account_id
    WHERE       (i.invoice_status LIKE 'SAVE%' OR i.invoice_date IS NULL)
    AND         a.lead_status IN ('SIGNED UP', 'BILLING')
    AND         a.account_position != 'DELETED'
    GROUP BY    a.account_id
) x
LEFT JOIN   mydb.account_owners o   ON      x.`CRM ID` = o.account_id
```

In this query, the final `LEFT JOIN` is the one that makes the row display more than once, despite the `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

[image]

Aside: ignore the fact that the columns in the above query have got 'friendly' names. This query is taken from a reporting tool that shows the columns based upon what SQL returns `:)`